# Character extraction

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to extract characters between an "=" and a space in a string in excel. however whenever I try to do this I get errors or it pulls data after a different space in the text string. The strings vary in their character length and what comes after the space.  Essentially I need to pull whatever is between the "=" and the space (so the number after "grips=" but not any of that gibberish after the number) examples of the text:

gbg bobbrazer gb3 360x2,5/6,25x50 4/8/22 grips=100 fls922 IE522-11

gbg bobbrazer bloodtrait 360x2,5/6,25x50 4/8/22 grips=12 IE0008

So for the above examples I would need the result to be "100" for the first string and "12" for the second. Everytime I use a Mid(left and LEN( combo I can make it work for specific sets but only if the gibberish at the end is the same for some reason. Current Formula I am using is this abomination:

=IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(LEFT(D2,FIND(" K",D2)-1),FIND("=",D2)+1,LEN(D2)),MID(LEFT(D2,FIND(" B",D2)-1),FIND("=",D2)+1,LEN(D2))),MID(LEFT(D2,FIND(" U",D2)-1),FIND("=",D2)+1,LEN(D2)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming:

- The '=' always exists;
- The portion of the text you'd like to extract is an integer;
- This integer is never more than 99 characters long;

You could try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,ROW($1:$99)))
```

Comment: For those interested, I got this idea orginally form [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/l7l9o1/comment/gl7q5ar/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) post on Reddit, with kudos to the original author. It seems to fit the job in this instance. It also includes a thorough explaination if one scrolls down.

Comment: A very clever and instructive use to isolate numeric values, indeed +:) If, however it's not always `"grips="` but changing context, it might be of some interest to get also the full (alphanumeric) word **before** the equal sign `=`. - So using Excel vers.2021+/MS365, you could use the following formula in `C1`:  `=LET(cell," "&A1,arr,ROW($1:$99),tokens,MID(cell,FIND("=",cell)-arr,arr),pos,MATCH(" *",tokens,0),INDEX(tokens,pos-1))`

Comment: You have to be careful with such constructions. For example, if `A1` contained "*gbg bobbrazer gb3 360x2,5/6,25x50 4/8/22 grips=10 APR922 IE522-11*" then this set-up would fail (at least for those with an English-language version of Excel). More rigorous is `=-LOOKUP(1,-(MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,ROW($1:$99))&"**0"))`

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `Mid` and `Find`. A combination of those two will be able to search for two specific characters and return the string in-between them.

Here is the Excel formula to do this:

`=MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("=",A1))-FIND("=",A1)-1)`

Since you tagged `VBA`, here is the VBA way to do this:

```vb
    Dim myString As String, PositionOfEquals As Long, PositionOfNextSpace As Long
    myString = [A1]
    PositionOfEquals = InStr(1, myString, "=")
    PositionOfNextSpace = InStr(PositionOfEquals, myString, " ")
    Debug.Print Mid(myString, PositionOfEquals + 1, PositionOfNextSpace - PositionOfEquals - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier to use `LET` and assign your values as you go along

```
=LET(text, I4, eq, IFERROR(FIND("=", text), 0), space, IFERROR(FIND(" ", text, eq), LEN(text)+1), MID(text, eq + 1, space-eq-1))
```

Comment: I'm so jealous whenever I see these clever answers using functions from the newer Excel versions. Important to note when attempting this solution: The `LET` function requires Excel 365 or Excel 2021 or newer.